# Right Docked Panel in Ext?

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to add a panel via Ext to an application that wasn't built using ext. I want the panel to be docked to the right of the screen and to be collapable / expandable. Is this possible considering I haven't built the rest of the app in Ext?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but might require a lot work. Basically you'd need to use `Ext.layout.BorderLayout` layout and put your panel in `east` region of it, and the original content in `center` region.

Comment: I was thinking something like that. I'd ideally want the docked panel to open over the content of the main app, rather than resizing it. It sounds like Ext isn't the best library for this scenario. Unforunately it's not really my decision.

Comment: BorderLayout can in fact do what you want. You just need to configure the region to `floatable: true`